# Forwarding rvalue into a thread where it is further forwarded to another function

Tags: multithreading, lambda, tuples, rvalue, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to create a **deadline** class which starts a thread in its constructor. Once the deadline (a time priod) occur within a thread, a function provided as argument should be executed.

The class'es contructor takes that function as a parameter, as well as arguments of that function.

I can provide parameter by value and by reference, but when providing rvalue as parameter, I get compile error, which I don't know how to solve.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace {
  std::atomic<bool> running{true};

  template <typename Period>
  using duration = std::chrono::duration<int64_t, Period>;

  template <typename PromiseType = void>
  class deadline {
    std::promise<PromiseType> stopper_{};
    std::thread thread_{};

  public:
    deadline() = delete;

    template <typename Period, typename Function, typename... Args>
    explicit deadline(const duration<Period> &interval, Function&& func, Args&&... args) noexcept {
      if (interval.count() > 0) {
        std::future<PromiseType> future{ stopper_.get_future() };

        using tuple = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
        auto decay_copied = std::make_unique<tuple>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        thread_ = std::thread(
          [](std::future<PromiseType>&& future,
             const duration<Period> &interval,
             Function&& func, decltype(decay_copied)&& params) {
          if (future.wait_for(interval) == std::future_status::timeout) {
            std::apply(func, *params);
          }
        }, std::move(future), std::cref(interval), std::forward<Function>(func), std::move(decay_copied));
      }
    }

    deadline(const deadline&) = delete;
    deadline(deadline&&) = delete;

    deadline& operator=(const deadline&) = delete;
    deadline& operator=(deadline&&) = delete;

    ~deadline() {
      stopper_.set_value();
      if (thread_.joinable()) {
        thread_.join();
      }
    }
  };
}

auto main() -> int {
  std::string test1{"test 1"};
  std::string test2{"test 2"};
  std::string test3{"test 3"};
  std::string test4{"test 4"};

  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  deadline dl(5s,
    [](
        std::string test_1
      , const std::string& test_2
      , std::string& test_3
      , std::string&& test_4
      ) {
        std::cout << test_1 << '\n';
        std::cout << test_2 << '\n';
        std::cout << test_3 << '\n';
        test_3 += " modified";
        std::cout << test_4 << '\n';

        running = false;
      }
      , test1
      , std::cref(test2)
      , std::ref(test3)
      , std::move(test4)
      //, "test 4"
  );

  while (running.load()) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }

  std::cout << test1 << '\n';
  std::cout << test2 << '\n';
  std::cout << test3 << '\n';
  std::cout << test4 << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The code could be checked here also:
https://godbolt.org/z/fx3a4szoY

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

When providing a const value (also a rvalue), it works, it doesn't work if I use std::move.